# When I plot this figure I can't view the maximum value and the minimum

Tags: python, matplotlib, interpolation, slice, contourf

How I write in the title my problem is, when I plot this slice graph, i can't see the maximum value and minimum value of `v1,v2,v3`.`v1,v2,v3` are 3 different arrays (for example 3 list of temperatures), `x` and `y` are the coordinates of `v1,v2,v3` in the same point. In my slice graph the levels represent the depth. 
I should have a maximum value (of temperature) in the first slice and in the last a minimum, but when i plot it can be seen a empty space correspond to max and min values and i don't know why.

How can I fix it? I hear all suggestions to make my code better

```
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.gca(projection='3d')

x_list = np.array(East)
y_list = np.array(North)

xi, yi = np.linspace(x_list.min(), x_list.max(), 100), np.linspace(y_list.min(), y_list.max(), 100)
xi, yi = np.meshgrid(xi, yi)


Vtot = V1,V2,V3,V4

rbf = scipy.interpolate.Rbf(x_list, y_list, V1, function='inverse')
zi = rbf(xi, yi)
rbf = scipy.interpolate.Rbf(x_list, y_list, V2, function='inverse')
zi2 = rbf(xi, yi)
rbf = scipy.interpolate.Rbf(x_list, y_list, V3, function='inverse')
zi3 = rbf(xi, yi)


levels = np.linspace(min(Ttot),max(Ttot), 20,endpoint=True)

ax.contour(xi, yi, 0 + .1 * zi, len(levels),linewidths=0.2,colors='b')
ax.contour(xi, yi, -6 + .1 * zi2, len(levels), linewidths=0.2, colors='b')
ax.contour(xi, yi, -12 + .1 * zi3, len(levels),linewidths=0.2, colors='b')


ax.contourf(xi, yi, 0 + .1 * zi, zdir='z', levels= .1*levels, cmap='jet')
ax.contourf(xi, yi, -6 + .1 * zi2, zdir='z', levels= -6 + .1*levels, cmap='jet')
ax.contourf(xi, yi, -12 + .1 * zi3, zdir='z', levels= -12 + .1*levels, cmap='jet')
ax.legend()

plt.show()
```

Results: 
[image: Slice Figure]

Can you explain what my problem is?

Comment: No, *you* need to explain what your problem is, such that other people can help you solve it. Does the plot not show the minimum? The minimum of *what* actually? What do you want to see? Please reword your question to clearly state in how far what you obtain is not what you expect and what exactly hinders you to obtain the desired plot. Also read [ask] and [mcve].